# Ubuntu server disk usage 91% and can't find why

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have two servers, one for production and one for staging.
In the staging server, when you go to `/usr/src` and hit `du -sh` you get a response in less than 1 seconds. In my production server, which is currently using 20% of cpu and 40% of ram, and the app in production running smooth, it takes almost 5 minutes to the very same command to return.
The staging server returns with 560Mb of disk usage while the production returns with 405Mb only. So in fact, this directory in the staging server is heavier and the response from this command returns immediately. What leads me to think that there tons of files instead of some big heavy files.

There shouldn't be too much differences between those servers, but there probably is. I try to find what.

Also, when going to `/` directory and hit: `df -h` (this time I get the response very quickly) I get this:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  652K  394M   1% /run
/dev/vda1        25G   22G  2.3G  91% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1003
```

And on the staging server, which has a clone of the DB from the prod server, which weights only 2gb approximately, this is the result:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            984M     0  984M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  616K  199M   1% /run
/dev/vda1        25G  4.7G   20G  20% /
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1004
```

As you can see, `/dev/vda1` 4.7GB only - VS 22GB in the prod server.
From my end, there is clearly havn't added anything that should make the prod server to be so bursted with the disk usage. The only thing I can think of, is inflated logs or something like that.

So I went to `/` dir and hit the command `du -sh` for each dir, went to `/var/logs` and cleared everything that shouldn't be there. and cleaned maybe 1 gb approx, still there is something takes huge disk space and I can't find what.

I think that it something related to the linux-headers, logs or something.

How can I verify that? How can I get exactly what consumes the disk usage?